# range-based for loop with a const container issue

Tags: c++11

I'm implementing some example from the book "A Tour of C++" by  Bjarne Stroustrup.
I have a template function to compute sum of elements (copied from the book):

```
template<typename Container, typename Value>
Value sum(const Container& c, Value v)
{   
  for (auto x : c)
    v+=x;
  return v;
}
```

I want to apply it to a template class Vector (defined in the book) which has a "begin" and "end" functions to support range-for loop (copied from the book):

```
   template<typename T>
   T∗ begin(Vector<T>& x)
   {
    return x.size() ? &x[0] : nullptr;
   }
   template<typename T>
   T∗ end(Vector<T>& x)
   {
    return begin(x)+x.size();
   }
```

when applied to Vector, for example  :

```
Vector<int> v={1,2,3,4};
int s=sum(v, 0);
```

this lead to a compilation error. However, when I remove const from the sum template function

```
 template<typename Container, typename Value>
 Value sum( Container& c, Value v)
```

it compiles.

1-  why it didn't work with the "const" ? If it is a problem with the "begin", "end" implementation,  how to implement them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are these the only versions of `begin` and `end`? Notice they take the vector by reference to non-`const`. To make `sum` compile, you should also add `const` overloads:

```
template<typename T>
const T∗ begin(const Vector<T>& x)
{
  return x.size() ? &x[0] : nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
const T∗ end(const Vector<T>& x)
{
  return begin(x)+x.size();
}
```

Note that this requires `Vector` to have a `const` overload of `operator[]`. That's a very reasonable requirement; if the original `Vector` doesn't have it (doubtful), you should add it.

Comment: That works! Thank you! This is missing in the book and should be added to the errata.